# .htaccess to serve specific pages with prefix path in front of it

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I need to serve these pages:

/category/*

As

/shop/category/*

I need the url to have `/shop` in front of `/category/` and it needs to handle all nested path structures within category also.

How can I do this via .htaccess preferred?

There is also a `/shop/` page that I do not want disturbed by any .htaccess edits.

So, I just need to serve `/category/` pages with the url having `/shop/category/` instead, is this possible via .htaccess?

So I'm a beginner here in .htaccess rewrites, but have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^category/$
RewriteRule ^shop/category/(.*)$ category/$1 [L]
```

It doesn't do anything tho...

Also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^category/(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /shop/category/$1? [R,L]
```

Again, no effect on anything.

I am using Wordpress, so it seems it has some power over my rewrite rule perhaps??  Anyways, here is my entire .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^shop/category/(.*)$ category/$1 [R,L]
```

Have tried the following within the `init` wordpress action also:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^/shop/category(?:/.*)?', '/category/$matches[1]', 'top');
```

No luck on this.

Ok, seems that I might be getting somewhere here...

The following `add_rewrite_rule` below matches only the first category, but doesn't match for child categories:

```
add_rewrite_rule('shop/category/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

The custom taxonomy that I am using is `product_category`, not wordpress default `category` since I don't want my product categories mixed with post categories.  So, I just need to figure out now, how to match all paths (which include child categories), for example:

`/category/gelest-inc/silanes-silicones/`

silanes-silicones is a child of gelest-inc, how to capture this in the rewrite rule above also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly following .htaccess should serve your requirements:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category(?:/.*)?$ /shop/$0 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Ok, that is redirecting to `/shop/category/*` properly, but it needs to load up the content from `/category/*`, so while it is changing the url structure now, it is giving me a 404, instead of loading the content from `/category/*`  can we change the url, but still load up the content from `/category/`?

Comment: That won't be possible just from .htaccess since this is Wirdpress. WP uses it's own rewrite API. Using that API you need to add a simple rule in the  `function.php` file of your theme.

Comment: I looked up a bit on this, and the `add_rewrite_rule` but I'm still not sure on how to do it in wordpress...  Can you provide an example perhaps?

Comment: Provided an example of the `add_rewrite_rule` that I'm trying to use within wordpress that doesn't work

Comment: Try: `function custom_rewrite_basic() { add_rewrite_rule('^shop/(category/.*)', '$matches[1]', 'bottom'); }` then in next line `add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');`

Comment: Any change you can weigh in on this topic here, that explains the problem a bit more?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340058/wordpress-child-categories-not-working-in-urls-like-they-should/42343233?noredirect=1#comment71847420_42343233 Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I will take a look at that question though I know only bit of WP :)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule says if HTTP_HOST is **catagory/** then rewritehomepage (^$ matches an empty uri eg : /) to /shop/catagory.  Your RewriteCond never meets as you are matching against HTTP_HOST header using URI in pattern.

If you want to redirect /catagory/ to /shop/catagory , you can use

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^catagory/([^/]*)/?$ /shop/catagory/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried your method here, but it is not working at all, it has no effect:  `RewriteRule ^shop/category/([^/]*)/?$ /category/$1 [L]`

Comment: For example, when I type in:  `http://localhost/category/gelest-inc/` it should change the url in browser to:  `http://localhost/shop/category/gelest-inc/` which it does not :(

Answer (score 0):

You have the WordPress rules, and *after* the rules comes the "shop" rule.

When the shop URI is not a real file or directory, requests for it will already be handled by the WordPress rules and rewritten to `index.php`. Apache then iterates a second time with `index.php`, but it doesn't match the shop rule and never redirects or rewrites.

---

To make this work the shop rule must come first

```
RewriteRule ^shop/category/(.*)$ category/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

---

Now it depends on what you want to achieve, redirect from

```
RewriteRule ^shop/category/(.*)$ category/$1 [R,L]
```

or to `shop/category`

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ shop/category/$1 [R,L]
```