# WordPress child categories not working in urls like they should

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using this plugin called, "Custom Post Type Permalinks", which kinda helps me to get a post type to line up with a custom taxonomy that I created called, `product_category`, but I can't get the product_category taxonomy links proper with `/shop/` in front of them that work with Child Categories also.

Basically, the custom post type is `product` and has a url structure like so:  /shop/category/{Category Parent}/{Category Child}/{Product Name} and looks like the following in functions.php when registering the custom post type:

```
register_post_type('product', array(
        'description'           => __('Products'),
        'label'                 => __('products'),
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'                  => _x('Product', 'Post Type General Name'),
            'singular_name'         => _x('Product', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
            'menu_name'             => __('Products'),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Product'),
            'all_items'             => __('All Products'),
            'view_item'             => __('View Product'),
            'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Product'),
            'add_new'               => __('Add New'),
            'edit_item'             => __('Edit Product'),
            'update_item'           => __('Update Product'),
            'search_items'          => __('Search Product'),
            'not_found'             => __('Not Found'),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Not Found in Trash')
        ),
        'taxonomies'            => array('product_category'),
        'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite'               =>  array('slug' => 'shop', 'with_front' => false),
        "cptp_permalink_structure" => "/category/%product_category%/%postname%/",
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true, // Needs to be set to true to be able to show the endpoints!
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'menu_position'         => 10,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-cart',
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page'
    )
);
```

The `cptp_permalink_structure` key allows me to assign `%product_category%` so that the categories (parent and children) are collected in the url and the product name is the last part of the path.  I needed to give this a slug, so I choose `shop` so that it has something as the slug and shop should come before category anyways.  All of the Product urls are working perfectly fine.  And look like this:  `/shop/category/{Category Parent}/{Category Child}/{Product Name}/`

Now for the custom taxonomy, I added within the function that gets triggered by the `init` action of WordPress and looks like this:

```
// I do not want to use 'category' since I don't want post categories mixed with product categories.
register_taxonomy('product_category', 'product', array(
    'label' => __('Category'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'shop/category', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false),
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Categories'),
        'singular_name' => __('Category'),
        'all_items' => __('All Categories'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Category'),
        'view_item' => __('View Category'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Category'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Category'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Categories'),
        'popular_items' => __('Popular Categories'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Categories with commas'),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or Remove Categories'),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from the most used Categories'),
        'not_found' => __('No Categories found')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'description' => 'Categories associated with Products.',
    'query_var' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
        'manage_terms' => 'manage_options', //by default only admin
        'edit_terms' => 'manage_options',
        'delete_terms' => 'manage_options',
        'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'  // means administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor'
    )
));
```

I've tried using `shop/category` for the rewrite slug of the taxonomy (as you can see above), which would be perfect, if only child category archive pages were not producing 404 pages.  So while:  `/shop/category/{Category Parent}/` and `/shop/category/{Category Child}/` works, `/shop/category/{Category Parent}/{Category Child}/` returns a 404 Error page.  So, I'm at a loss on how to get Child Categories showing as in `/shop/category/{Category Parent}/{Category Child}/`

Note:  If I change to just `category` as the rewrite slug, Children Categories are lining up properly like so:  `/category/{Category Parent}/{Category Child}`, but the problem is, I need `/shop/` before `/category/` here.

How to do this?  Been trying to figure this out for days now, with tons of different ways, tried adding a rewrite rule also (when changing the rewrite slug to just `category`).

```
add_rewrite_rule('shop/category/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

But the rewrite rule doesn't work for Child Categories either.  And returns the parent category archive instead of the child.

As I've tested this within the archive.php file with the following code:

```
$tax_slug = get_query_var('product_category');
echo '<pre>', var_dump($tax_slug), '</pre>';
```

And returns the parent category slug instead of the child on child categories.

Any help is appreciated here, I've been pulling my hair out... going bald!

**EDIT - Possible Method that might work**

So, basically, it might be as simple as creating another `BASE` for that taxonomy in the Permalinks section of the admin.  But how to create a BASE for a custom taxonomy?  There is already a BASE for categories and tags, but if this could work, I would need a BASE for `product_category`, and the slug for the `product_category` taxonomy could just be `category`, and the BASE would add `shop` before it for all links.  But how to create a BASE for a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the query argument in functions.php. I tried your code in my local installation and it worked fine with mine.

The updated code for this is :

```
/* Have WordPress match postname to any of our public post types (post, page, product)
 * All of our public post types can have /post-name/ as the slug, so they better be unique across all posts
 * By default, core only accounts for posts and pages where the slug is /post-name/
 */

function na_parse_request( $query ) {

     if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
     }

     if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'product' ) );
     }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```

This basically changes the query string when you update any changes to the permalink and rewrite rules. Here you post type value "product" has been given to set query.

Hope this will work for you.

Thank You

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but child category archive pages do not work for me.  They return a 404 page instead.  I will post up some screenshots...

Comment: @SolomonClosson have you tried my code in functions.php ? I tried in my local computer it worked for me as from you same instruction. So i think this above code will help you but make sure you paste it in functions.php in theme folder.

Comment: Yes, I placed your code in functions.php in the theme path, resaved permalinks, it does not work.

Comment: @SolomonClosson you desired permalink is www.example.com/shop/category/category-parent/category-child/product right?

Comment: No, desired permalink is:  `www.example.com/shop/category/category-parent/category-child‌​/`  That is the link that causes 404 error.

Comment: @SolomonClosson oh sorry then i though you want single product page but with that url structure .. ok then i think i need to see my code for you desired update now ...

Comment: I still need `www.example.com/shop/category/category-parent/category-child‌​/product` to work also.

Comment: @SolomonClosson the above answer must work for www.example.com/shop/category/cat-parent/cat-child/product

Comment: Yes, it works fine for product post names, but it doesn't work for child category links, which I need it to work for.

Comment: @SolomonClosson ya i am working to fix your problem .. hope i succeed.

Comment: In short, I need `www.example.com/shop/category/category-child/` to be converted to:  `www.example.com/shop/category/category-parent/category-child/`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after looking at the dump of rules from the `rewrite_rules_array` filter.

I added in this bit in the wordpress `init` action and now works:

```
add_rewrite_rule('shop/category/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Thanks to all for your help with this.  The slug for the custom taxonomy is the same at:  `shop/category`

The important thing here in order to get child categories working is this bit:  `&cpage=$matches[2]` which I wan't aware of and also didn't even know the name of the child category was `cpage`, this was discovered while looking at the rewrite_rules_array output which I just dumped on the page to see.